# What is it called when punctuation changes the meaning of a sentence?

Tags: meaning, punctuation

Is there a word describing a sentence whose meaning is changed by moving the punctuation? For example,

> Let’s eat, Mommy!

and

> Let’s eat Mommy!

Comment: If you'll notice, when you close your eyes, you can still hear the difference. It's a difference in **pronunciation**, not punctuation. Punctuation is just a brain-damaged part of Modern English spelling, which -- as you may have noticed -- doesn't represent Modern English very well.

Comment: @John, yes, but, alas, nowadays teenagers don't realize how it is dangerous to practice punctuation in language usage.

Comment: For the written language, which you can hear if you read it silently or aloud to yourself, not only is there a difference in pronunciation, but there is a difference in what's called _writing mechanics_: punctuation is one aspect of writing mechanics. There's no term to describe what you're asking about. It's simply called "changing the meaning by changing the punctuation" or, in this particular case, "adding a comma that wasn't there before", not "moving a comma that wasn't there before".

Comment: this usually falls under syntactic (or structural) ambiguity, even though as @JohnLawler points out there is a difference in pronunciation.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: To borrow and adapt a slogan from [the NRA](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/michael-j-tansey/guns-dont-kill-peoplethe-_b_2342220.html), *"Punctuation doesn't kill language - bad writers do!"*.

Comment: I don't know the technical name for this phenomenon, but I've heard the phenomenon alluded to as _"eats shoots and leaves"_, which is the title of a [book](http://www.amazon.com/Eats-Shoots-Leaves-Commas-Difference/dp/0399244913) that addresses this topic. Also related: [this classic ELU answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/82986/really-nice-mat/82989#82989).

Comment: Now that jlovegren has introduced the term "syntactic (or structural) ambiguity", a one-word term for adding the comma (in this case in which the first version is macabre) does suggest itself: **clarification**. The only times when this kind of structural ambiguity is a problem for the spoken language are when the speaker is carefully pronouncing each word without regard to its function and the required stress and intonation pattern for the sentence, and when a poor text-to-speech reader is rendering text into improperly stressed and intoned mechanical speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think you need to aim higher.

Comment: That's got to be either _Words don't kill language, writers do_ or _Writers don't kill language, words do_ or _Writers don't kill language, too many words at one time in a single phrase or clause or sentence or paragraph do_ or _Writers don't kill language, clichés do_.

Comment: @Robusto: You mean we should go gunning for the language mavens and copy editors? Or shall we go straight to the top and blame it all on Murdoch and his downmarket newspapers?

Comment: Commas don't kill people; they only punctuate them. Note all this metaphoric violence stirred up by commas. Figments of the fictive imagination, commas. Pay attention to the pronunciation. Then reproduce the intonation by any means you can. Including commas, if you need them; and [don't forget the semicolons](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/punctuation.html).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia page for [Eats, Shoots & Leaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eats,_Shoots_&_Leaves), such ambiguous constructions are examples of [amphiboly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amphiboly) or [amphibology](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amphibology) (which come from the Greek word for *ambiguity*).